# How to hide a div when another div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and I've hit a bit of a snag.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mainpage-tabs-area">
<ul class="nav cf">
    <li class="tb-one"><a href="#description" class="current">BTN1</a></li>
    <li class="tb-two"><a href="#tabtwo">BTN2</a></li>
    <li class="tb-three"><a href="#tabthree">BTN3</a></li>
    <li class="tb-four"><a href="#tabfour">BTN4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="list-wrap">
    <ul id="description">
        <li>Hello, I am a description</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="tabtwo" class="hide">
      <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="tabthree" class="hide">
        <li></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="tabfour" class="hide">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- END List Wrap -->
            </div> <!-- END Organic Tabs -->
```

And here is my current jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabContent = $('ul.list-wrap').find('li').text();
    if ($.trim(tabContent) === "") {
        $('ul.nav li').hide();
    }
});
```

What I want to be able to do is just the jQuery to check every li in .list-wrap and if that li is empty then remove the corresponding li in .nav as this is for a tab system where if no content is entered, they don't want it displaying.

Any suggestions for a newbie?

Nick

Comment: When the html is generated, you could also add a class / set an arrtibute on empty <li> elements, eg class="empty'. Then with jQuery you can iterate through those with some help of the answer below. This could speed things up when the amount of elements grows. Or better, do not even generate the tabs.

Comment: oops, you do want them, just hidden. But you could do this upon generation of the page as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd iterate through the list items, check the length of each node's text, and hide the corresponding tab with:

```js
$('.list-wrap li').each(function(i){
    if(!$(this).text().length) $('#mainpage-tabs-area li').eq(i).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainpage-tabs-area">
    <ul class="nav cf">
        <li class="tb-one"><a href="#description" class="current">BTN1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tb-two"><a href="#tabtwo">BTN2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tb-three"><a href="#tabthree">BTN3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tb-four"><a href="#tabfour">BTN4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="list-wrap">
        <ul id="description">
            <li>Hello, I am a description</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="tabtwo" class="hide">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="tabthree" class="hide">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="tabfour" class="hide">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- END List Wrap -->
</div>
<!-- END Organic Tabs -->
```

The `i` in the `each()` function is the index of the element that the loop is on, and that allows you to target the corresponding tab element and hide it.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I am doing okay with the basics of jQuery, so any help is really grateful, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
$('.list-wrap ul li').each(function(){
    var cnt = $('.list-wrap ul li').index( $(this) );
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if ($.trim(txt)==''){
        $('.nav li').eq(cnt).hide();
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/45cnnzq1/)</kbd>

Comment: Alright, j08691's answer is more concise, more elegant and about 10 mins faster... Well done.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest this If you are not making infinite lists

```js
$('.tb-two').hide(); //if tabtwo is empty
$('.tb-hree').hide(); //if tabthree is empty
 and so on...
```

Comment: I did not down vote this, but I wanted to - I think that good answer should work in a fiddle. Your answer is not a complete answer as your comments demonstrate.